# breeze: custom enum values

Tags: enums, breeze

Enums come back from the server as myEnum.SomeValue but what I'd like to show on screen is a formatted value such as "some value" instead of SomeValue. 
That could be part of an attribute on the server-side model but it won't be passed in the metadata.
What's the best place then to do that kind of thing with breeze ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've discussed the idea of "extensible" metadata for Breeze but have not yet implemented it.  Please vote for this [here](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions).

But in the meantime, there is nothing stopping you from "enhancing" the metadata returned by Breeze yourself.  The best way to do this would be to add your own properties to either the "MetadataStore", "EntityType" or "DataProperty" classes.

The advantage of adding your custom metadata to existing metadata objects is that this data will be available whenever you work with any of the basic Breeze metadata.

Perhaps something like this: ( I haven't actually confirmed that this code is correct)

```
var custType = myEntityManager.metadataStore.getEntityType("Customer");

// assume that the 'status' property is actually an enumerated value where you want to 
// add some custom metadata.
var statusProp = custType.getProperty("status"); 

// enumDescriptions is your custom property
statusProp.enumDescriptions = { 
  "PaidUp": "Paid Up", 
  "Delinq": "Delinquent",
  "InArr":  "In Arrears"
};
```

Now anywhere that you get given the "status" dataProperty, ( such as in a Validation), you will also have access to your "enumDescriptions"

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: do you think you could provide a short example on how to enhance the metadata of an enum on then client side ? I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do it, even after reading the doc. I know how to add custom properties in the registerEntityTypeCtor  but what method do I use to add metadata to the metadatastore ?

Comment: great ! That should be enough to get me out of my misery :) Thanks for helping !